# Specify customers with no orders

Tags: php, mysql

I have a customers table like this

```
customers_id   |   customers_date_added
-----------------------------
   1           | 2012-10-13 09:31:38
   2           | 2013-12-13 08:31:38
   3           | 2014-09-13 10:31:38
   4           | 2013-08-13 09:31:38
   5           | 2011-07-13 14:31:38
```

and an order table like this

```
   orders_id   |   customers_id
-------------------------------
     1         |      2
     2         |      3
     3         |      5
     4         |      5
     5         |      2
```

I try to get the customers who have no orders and registered in 2012 and 2013. In this case I would like to get the customers_id 1 and 4.

This doesn't work.

```
SELECT customers_id
FROM customers
WHERE  customers_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT customers_id
  FROM   orders
)
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) = '2013'
OR  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) = '2012'
```

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_added) = '2013'` instead of `AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) = '2013'`

Comment: you need to use braces when you use AND so your query should be SELECT customers_id
FROM customers
WHERE  customers_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT customers_id
  FROM   orders
)
AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) = '2013'
OR  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) = '2012')

Comment: @ pbaldauf I fixed the wrong the column name

Comment: Actually it works fine... see [THE FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ba7e/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT customers.customers_id
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN order ON customers.customers_id = order.customers_id
WHERE order.customers_id IS NULL
AND customers.customers_date_added BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT customers_id
FROM   customers
WHERE  customers_id NOT IN (
SELECT customers_id
FROM   order
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT customers_id
FROM customers 
WHERE customers_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id FROM orders)
AND   date_added BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your statement works, see the fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ba7e/6)

You could also do this here with the same result

```
SELECT customers_id
FROM   customers
WHERE  customers_id NOT IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT customers_id
          FROM   orders
       )
AND customers_date_added LIKE '2013%'
OR  customers_date_added LIKE '2012%'
```

OR

```
SELECT customers_id
FROM   customers
WHERE  customers_id NOT IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT customers_id
          FROM   orders
       )
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM customers_date_added) IN ('2013', '2012')
```